Smart selects Django 5.0.6 Problemas al implementar material desing en Django Admin
Concretamente implemente smart selects ya que ayuda mucho a la hora de poder filtrar datos en cadena especialmente en el uso de llaves foraneas.
el problema que tengo que los filtros no funcionan al implementar django-material-admin para mejorar la interfaz del administrador
Codigo Models.Py
from django.db import models
import datetime
from django import forms 
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey


# Create your models here.

class Pais(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Nombre del Pais:')
    moneda = models.CharField(max_length=5,verbose_name='Moneda en circulacion:')
    bandera = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagenes/',verbose_name='Imagen de Bandera:', null=True)       
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Pais')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Paises')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)
    
    
    def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
        self.bandera.delete()
        super().delete()     

class Propietario(models.Model):        
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre de Propietario')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Numero de Telefono')
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Correo de Contacto')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Propietario')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Propietarios')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)


class Empresa(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_propietario = ChainedForeignKey(
        Propietario,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre de Empresa')
    nombre_juridico = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre Juridico de Empresa')
    nit = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='NIT')
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Direccion Principal')
    numero_constitucion = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Numero de Constitucion')
    fecha_constitucion = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today(),verbose_name='Fecha de Constitucion') 
    fecha_inscripcion = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today(),verbose_name='Fecha de Inscripion')
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Correo de Contacto')
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=10,verbose_name='Telefono de Contacto')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Empresa')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Empresas')


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)    

class Establecimiento(models.Model):
    id= models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Numero de Establecimiento:')
    nombre = models.TextField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Nombre de Establecimiento:')
    fecha_apertura = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today(),verbose_name='Fecha de apertura:')
    direccion = models.TextField(max_length=250,verbose_name='Direccion de Establecimiento')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Establecimiento')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Establecimientos')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.nombre)
    


class UnidadMedida(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name =('Unidad de Medida')
        verbose_name_plural =('Unidades de Medida')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)

class CategoriaProductos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais',default=1)
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Categoria Productos')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Categorias Productos')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)

class SubCategoriaProductos(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais',default=1)
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True,
        default=1)
    id_cat_prod = ChainedForeignKey(
        CategoriaProductos,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Sub Categoria Productos')
        verbose_name_plural =('Sub Categorias Productos')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)

class Producto(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Codigo de Pais")
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_establecimiento = ChainedForeignKey(
        Establecimiento,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_unidad_medida = ChainedForeignKey(
        UnidadMedida,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_categoria = ChainedForeignKey(
        CategoriaProductos,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_sub_categoria = ChainedForeignKey(
        SubCategoriaProductos,
        chained_field="id_categoria",
        chained_model_field="id_cat_prod",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    codigo = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=150)
    combustible = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    idp = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Producto')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Productos')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)

class Tanque(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_establecimiento = ChainedForeignKey(
        Establecimiento,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_producto = ChainedForeignKey(
        Producto,
        chained_field="id_establecimiento",
        chained_model_field="id_establecimiento",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    capacidad = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Tanque')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Tanques')
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.descripcion)

class Bomba(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_establecimiento = ChainedForeignKey(
        Establecimiento,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Numero de Bomba:')
    descripcion = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    acum_importe = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    autoservicio = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    notas = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Bomba')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Bombas')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.numero)

class ProductoBomba (models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_pais = models.ForeignKey(Pais,on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Codigo de Pais')
    id_empresa = ChainedForeignKey(
        Empresa,
        chained_field="id_pais",
        chained_model_field="id_pais",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_establecimiento = ChainedForeignKey(
        Establecimiento,
        chained_field="id_empresa",
        chained_model_field="id_empresa",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_bomba = ChainedForeignKey(
        Bomba,
        chained_field="id_establecimiento",
        chained_model_field="id_establecimiento",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    id_producto = ChainedForeignKey(
        Producto,
        chained_field="id_establecimiento",
        chained_model_field="id_establecimiento",
        show_all=False,
        auto_choose=True,
        sort=True)
    activo = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Producto Bomba')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Productos Bombas')

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "{}".format(self.id)


En la siguiente imagen se muestra como no se recargan los datos en los selet posteriores.
Vale la pena mencionar que esto si funciona si se usa el modelo original del administrador.

En mi caso de momento he optado por continuar con el desarrollo usando la plantilla de administrador por defecto pero necesito saber si sera posible implementar los smart selects en mi proyecto o si necesariamente debo usar otra libreria
